# I am conducting an experiment with oil eating bacteria. However, I am struggling to find a method to check how much oil they cleaned?

Tags: bacteriology, experimental-design, environment, experiment

I am experimenting to determine the optimum conditions for microbes to break down motor oil. The conditions I am going to test are different pH levels to resemble freshwater pH and saltwater pH. I will be using the chemical NaCl to adjust the salinity of the solution.

I have researched and found that one method is using a standard plate count. To just count the bacteria after incubating them for a few hours with the oil and pH concentration. The greater the number of bacteria, the more oil was degraded.

But my professor wants me to measure exactly how much oil is degraded by the bacteria to make a distinction from how much oil was at the beginning to how much is left at the end of the experiment.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site and [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, it appears that you are looking for methods to quantitate how much oil is present in a solution? If so, that isn't really a biology question. In addition, it is generally true on SE sites that you are expected to show evidence of prior research. For both of these reasons your question is may be closed or downvoted.

Comment: You could measure and test just one component of the oil. Perhaps make sure that the oil is the only energy source for the bacteria. Measuring oil degradation or actual consumption?

Comment: Centrifuge out the oil and weigh it?

Comment: is the oil a purified hydrocarbon, or a commercial motor oil which can consist of up to 30% additives including various detergents, surfactants, friction modifiers, corrosion inhibitors, etc. In either case, a hexane wash (or two) of the spent media (after harvesting cells) would likely removed most of the residual oil, but it's hard to say how much of the additive package might be left behind. Make sure to use an appropriately sized separation funnel. Probably also want to work with an analytical chemist to quantify residual hydrocarbons compared to the inputs.